# Perl: How to make sure overridden method is called when accessed from within the base class

Tags: perl, inheritance, overriding

I have a base class which calls a method which is overridden in a child class, in Perl.  Currently, it still calls the base class version of the method, but I want it to call the base if there is one.  Here is a simplified rendition of my code:

```
package Test;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub Main
{
    my $self = shift;
    return $self->SomeFunc();
}

sub SomeFunc
{
    my $self = shift;
    #...
    return 1;
}

package Test2;

use strict;
use warnings;

use base qw(Test);

sub SomeFunc
{
    my $self = shift;
    #...
    return 0;
}

package main;
use Test2;

my $test = new Test2();
print $test->Main();
```

and I am getting a 1 when I run this!

PS my apologies, I'm not used to creating examples in working perl code, please forgive the obvious errors.

Comment: You're not! Getting a `1`, that is. You're getting `Can't locate object method "new" via package "Test2"`

Comment: hah, you're right... hold on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem would be in your constructor, but you don't have one so your code doesn't even do what you say it does

You have probably written something like

```
sub new {
    bless {};
}
```

which blesses an empty hash into the *current* package. Instead you need to take the class name from the first parameter passed to the constructor, like this

You should also avoid using capital letters in your lexical identifiers as they are reserved for global identifiers like package names. If you must use CamelCase then at least makeSureTheFirstLetterIsLowerCase. The standard for both Perl and Python is to use the much_clearer_snake_case

#### Test.pm

```
package Test;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    bless {}, $class;
}

sub main {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->some_func();
}

sub some_func {
    my $self = shift;
    'Test::some_func';
}
```

#### Test2.pm

```
package Test2;

use strict;
use warnings;

use parent 'Test';

sub some_func {
    my $self = shift;
    'Test2::some_func';
}
```

#### main.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $test = Test->new;
print $test->main, "\n";

$test = Test2->new;
print $test->main, "\n";
```

#### output

```
Test::some_func
Test2::some_func
```

Comment: Good points -- to be honest I just hacked together this example from my much more complex actual code.  I'm not really used to putting together perl bits outside of my normal context, but I'm learning!  I'm not sure that what you suggested will work in my original application which does have new in a base class above.  However, it does look like you answered the question the way I phrased it.

Answer (score 1):

`new` doesn't mean anything in perl unless you make a function with that method name.

You need to `bless` an object

You can either directly `bless` an object

```
my $test = { };
bless $test, "Test2";
```

or make a new method that does the blessing for you:

```
sub new{
    my $class = shift;
    my $test = { };
    bless $test, $class;
}
```